# Specifying which core to use while running python code from command line

Tags: python, macos, unix, command-line, cpu-cores

I am using a Mac OS with 8 cores. When running a `.py` file from terminal, 
I use `python file.py`. But I am wondering if it is possible to specify which core to use. Something like `python file.py core 6`

This might be helpful while running heavy repetitive work with few change in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `processor affinity` on Mac OS. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Performance/RN-AffinityAPI/) it is unsupported.

> OS X does not export interfaces that identify processors or control
>   thread placement—explicit thread to processor binding is not
>   supported. Instead, the kernel manages all thread placement. 
>   Applications expect that the scheduler will, under most circumstances,
>   run its threads using a good processor placement with respect to cache
>   affinity.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the UNIX utility "nice", it lets you run processes with more or less priority.

The priority levels runs from -20 (top priority) to 19 (lowest). For example, to run tar and gzip at the lowest priority level:

```
$ nice -n 19 tar -czvf file.tar.gz bigfiletocompress
```

If you have a process running, use ps to find the process ID, and then use renice to change it’s priority level:

```
$ renice -n 19 -p 987 32
```

This would change processes 987 and 32 to priority level 19.